# AWS CDK RDS Construct - Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret stores default port and the given custom port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

As shown below, I am trying to create an RDS cluster in AWS CDK with AuroraMySql engine and custom port. I have `Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret()` method used to generate password, for some reason the generated secret has 3306 as port and not the custom port I have provided.

```js
const clusterProps: IDatabaseClusterProps = {
    clusterIdentifier: clusterIdentifier,
    engine: DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({version: AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_3_01_0}),
    instances: clusterResourcesProps?.instances,
    instanceProps: {
        instanceType: clusterResourcesProps?.instanceType,
        vpc: clusterResourcesProps.vpc,
        vpcSubnets: {
            subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC
        },
        securityGroups: [securityGroup]
    },
    port: 5555,
    defaultDatabaseName: DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME,
    removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    credentials: Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret("db_user", {
        secretName: "mysql_secret"
    })
}
```

Here is the generated secret

```json
{
    "dbClusterIdentifier": “cluster_identifier”,
    "password": “generated_password”,
    "dbname": “db”_user,
    "engine": "mysql",
    "port": 3306,
    "host": “db”_host,
    "username": “db_user”
}
```

Has anyone had this issue before and how did you resolve it?

Update: It worked somehow after recreating the CDK app.

Comment: Is this right after creating the stack, or after updating it?

Comment: Seems like this happens while creating the stack